# UpdateView won't save form and I get 404 error after I press save

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-generic-views

As the title says, I am having difficulty making UpdateView work. When I press save the form doesn't save and I get a 404 error with the message No User matches the given query. I am having a really tough time trying to get this work and have spent hours looking at examples online but still can't work out where I am going wrong! If you could shine some light on this it would be appreciated!

Just to clarify I want my user to be able to edit their project, and only that user can edit it. I suspect I could be doing multiple things wrong!

urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^register_profile/$', views.register_profile, name='register_profile'),
        url(r'^update_profile/$', views.update_profile, name='update_profile'),
        url(r'^create_project/$', login_required(views.CreateProject.as_view()), name='create_project'),
        url(r'^update_project/(?P<username>\w+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', login_required(views.UpdateProject.as_view()), name='update_project'),
        url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.profile_page, name='user_profile'),
        url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.project_page, name='user_project'),
        )
```

views

```
class UpdateProject(UpdateView):
    model = UserProject
    form_class = UserProjectForm
    template_name = 'howdidu/update_project.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(UpdateProject, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if obj.user != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied() #or Http404
        return obj

    def form_valid(self, form):
        userproject = form.save(commit=False)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        userproject.save()
        self.object = userproject
        return super(UpdateProject, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        project_username = self.request.user.username
        project_slug = self.object.slug
        return reverse('user_project', kwargs={'username':project_username, 'slug': project_slug})
```

models

```
class UserProject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_overview = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    project_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='project_images', blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    project_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    project_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    project_followers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True) #should this be unique or not?

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(UserProject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

project.html template

```
{% extends 'howdidu/base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}Project{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}

        {% if project %}

        <h1>{{ project.title }}</h1>
        <img src="{{ project.project_picture.url }}" width = "300" height = "300"  />
        <h3>{{ project.project_overview }}</h3>
        <p><a href="{% url 'update_project' project_user.username project.slug %}">Edit project</a></p>

        {% else %}
            The specified project {{ project.title }} does not exist!
        {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

update_project.html template

```
{% extends 'howdidu/base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}Update project{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}

        <h1>Edit your project</h1>

        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UserProjectForm" method="post" action="/update_project/">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action is `/update_project/`, but this doesn't match your url pattern for updating projects. Instead, the url matches the `views.profile_page` view, which treats `update_project` as a username. This raises a 404, since you don't have a user with that username.

If you remove the form `action` attribute, the form will submit to the current page, which I believe is what you want.

Alternatively you can change the action to

```
action="{% url 'update_project' project_user.username project.slug %}"
```

If you do this, you'll have to make sure that the variables are in the template context.

Comment: oh man! thank you! the amount of time I wasted for that silly mistake! With regards to security and only allowing the projects user to edit it, have I gone about it the right way?

Comment: Your `get_object` method looks ok to me (make sure to test it though!). It might be better to return 404 if the user is not authorised, because returning 403 leaks information that the user exists.